# TypeError: showToastrMessage.init is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling, typeerror

I am new to javascript. There is something wrong with my Javascript code but I don't understand what it is. Help me Please with this.

```
var showToastrMessage = function(){
toastr.success('sdfsdfd');
}
jQuery(document).ready(function() { showToastrMessage.init() }); //This line gives error saying "showToastrMessage.init is not a function".
```

Here is my Console log.

```
ERROR TypeError: showToastrMessage.init is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:26:55)
at d (<anonymous>:1:39736)
at u (<anonymous>:1:40050)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4744)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
at ZoneTask.invokeTask (zone.js:495)
at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:484)
at timer (zone.js:2065)
```

Comment: Make sure the path is correct for the `toast` js and the file is not showing 404. that is the only issue

Comment: There is no error in path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying do do?

If you want to run showToastrMessage function,
try `showToastrMessage()` instead of `showToastrMessage.init()`.

You can also use `showToastrMessage.call()` or `showToastrMessage.apply()`.

Comment: Yes, Thanks to you. I removed the init() and the error is gone. I was just following some code and he used the init(). I'm so stupid.